# json4s convert inherited class to json

Tags: json, scala, lift, json4s

I am trying to serialize / deserialize to json with json4s native the following case class :

`case class UserId(value: String) extends MappedTo[String] with Guid`

`case class FootballTeamId(value: String) extends Guid`

```
trait Guid extends Id[String] with MappedTo[String]

object Guid {

  import scala.reflect.runtime._
  import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

  def next[T <: Guid : TypeTag]: T = {
    val tt = typeTag[T]
    val constructor: MethodSymbol = tt.tpe.members.filter {
      m ⇒
        m.isMethod && m.asMethod.isConstructor
    }.head.asMethod
    currentMirror.reflectClass(tt.tpe.typeSymbol.asClass).reflectConstructor(constructor)(UUID.randomUUID().toString).asInstanceOf[T]
  }

}
```

I can do like this :

```
  case object UserIdSerializer extends CustomSerializer[UserId](format => ({
    case JString(s) => {
      UserId(s)
    }
  }, {
    case s: UserId => JString(s.value)
  }))
```

and have one custom serializer by type, but I'd rather be dry and have one custom serialiser that would do the job for all object of type Guid. I had no luck. I would be grateful for any help I could get on the topic !

Thanks

Comment: don't know about json4s, but if you are willing to have a look at Play-JSON, check http://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-json/  and http://pedrorijo.com/blog/scala-json-part2/

Comment: I think `net.liftweb.mongodb.{JsonObjectMeta, JsonObject}` in lift-json would solve your problem, for more, you can check this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36097379/how-to-use-lift-jsons-class-extractor-constructor-mongo-bson-array/36114083#36114083).